# How can I send multiple variables in Yajra datatable return?

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I have some calculations and values in my controller and I want to send these variables in return method of the yajra datatable like this

Can I do that ? if no ! then tell me best method to do that. Thanks in advance

````
$values= Table::get();
$new_val='demo';
return Datatables::of($values,$new_val)->make(true);```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
$values= Table::get();
$new_val='demo';
return Datatables::of($values,$new_val)->make(true);
```

Comment: doesn't work, it tells you clearly that it is expecting a parameter not two
datatables()->of($oneparameter)

Answer (score 0):

after long hours trying in various ways to be able to send an additional variable to the json that it generates, I have found the solution.

The first thing you have to assign your datatable content to a variable something like this:

```
$datatable = datatables()->of($data)
->addIndexColumn()
...
->make(true);
```

Finally this is what you have to do to join the json that generates datatable any value:

```
$data     = $datatable->getData(true);
$data['additionalcontentdatatable'] = $additionalcontentdatatable;

return $data;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can edit column with values like this

```
return Datatables::of($values)->editColumn('columnname', function ($n) {
            return $columnvalue;
        })->make(true);
```

Comment: But the value of ```$columnvalue``` will be go into the ```<tbody>``` of the datatable and I want to use that value outside the datatable.